# How do I automatically delete Docker images from Harbor?

Tags: bash, docker, curl, docker-registry, harbor

I'm using the harbor for docker images.

I want to automatically delete images from the docker 1 month ago.

Is there a method you know?

Answer (score 4):

There is tag retention feature that comes with 1.9.0 version. You can set a rule and retain tags that you want to keep.
https://goharbor.io/docs/2.0.0/working-with-projects/working-with-images/create-tag-retention-rules/#how-tag-retention-rules-work

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a harbor administrator. Alternatively, if you code, you can use its API in order to delete images given certain kind of rules.

But I agree that tag retention is simpler than using its API. I like to use its API, because I can customize the way I want the artifacts will be deleted (whether or not there is a tag in it etc).